# How can I use ether.js to listen for MetaMask events like `chainChained`?

Tags: metamask, events, ethers.js

I was wondering how can I use ethers.js to listen to MetaMask events like `accountsChanged` and `chainChanged` instead of `ethereum.on`? I already set my ether.js provider with `window.ethereum`. This is what I tried so far but it is not working.

```js
const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(ethereum);

// Listeners
provider.on("accountsChanged", (accounts) => {
  console.log("account change happened");
  dispatch(updateAccount(accounts[0]));
});

provider.on("chainChanged", (chainId) => {
  console.log(`network chain changed ${chainId}}`);
  alert("Network changed!");
  window.location.reload();
});
```

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I am trying to capture network /account changes but I had no success; Thank you in advance and regards

Answer (score 1):

Those events are [EIP-1193](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1193#events-1) specific. An ethers Provider **is not related** to an EIP-1193 compliant Provider. An ethers Provider is a higher-level interface compared to an EIP-1193-compliant Provider. They don't necessarily have those events that are defined in the EIP-1193 standard. The ethers library creates a strong division between the operation a **Provider** can perform and those of a **Signer**, which for example Web3.js lumps together. [A Provider in ethers is a read-only abstraction to access blockchain data.](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/providers/provider/#Provider) They should have named it something else to avoid confusion.

See the common terminology in [ethers' documentation](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/getting-started/#getting-started--glossary).

That all said, there are of course ways to listen to events.

1. [These](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/providers/provider/#Provider--events) are the supported events on an ethers Provider, and [in addition](https://docs.metamask.io/guide/ethereum-provider.html), you can use the `network` event that is pretty much the same as the `chainChanged` EIP-1193 event.

```js
const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum, "any");
provider.on("network", (newNetwork, oldNetwork) => {
  // When a provider makes its initial connection, it emits a "network"
  // event with a null oldNetwork along with the newNetwork. So, if the
  // oldNetwork exists, it represents a changing network
  if (oldNetwork) {
    // chain has changed
  }
});
```

2. You could also try to access the EIP-1193-compliant provider that is usually injected into the website by your wallet. So, **as long as you have a wallet installed, set up, and connected and it supports such events**, then you can listen to them using the following code.

   Note that `provider.provider` might not be available on certain ethers providers (i.e.: `Web3Provider`).

```js
provider?.provider?.on("chainChanged", (chainId) => {
  // Handle the new chain
});
```

3. This is what you already mentioned in your question. You also have direct access to the global EIP-1193-compliant-provider that your wallet injects. This injected global API is available via `window.ethereum`. [See how MetaMask does it.](https://docs.metamask.io/guide/ethereum-provider.html)

   You could directly listen to the event on this provider but I guess my preference would be to use ethers and you asked about the other solutions anyway.

```js
window.ethereum.on('chainChanged', (chainId) => {
  // Handle the new chain.
});
```

*References*

- https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/discussions/1560
- https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/issues/1396
- https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/issues/2842